# make text box read only according to login form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, authentication

In my access database , i have login form which open next after successful login attempt, but now i need one modification which i don't know how to do it:
There are only two users using this database and both use same form to enter the data, however based on the user some text boxes in the form need to be read only or hide, kindly help me how to achieve this..

The login form code is :

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnlogin_Click()
    Dim RS As Recordset
    Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("logintable", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    RS.FindFirst "UserName='" & Me.txtUsername & "'"

    If RS.NoMatch = True Then
        Me.lblwronguser.Visible = True
        Me.txtUsername.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.lblwronguser.Visible = False

    If RS!Password <> Nz(Me.txtPassword, "") Then
        Me.lblwrongpassword.Visible = True
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.lblwrongpassword.Visible = False
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Login screen"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Main Menu"
End Sub
```

and i want something like this in between:

```
If Me.txtPassword = "trial" Then
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Login screen"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmwhatdates"
    Form!frmwhatdates!cmdfilter.Visible = False
    Exit Sub
End If
```

**but after execution the error is showing**

```
 "Runtime Error 2467 The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist"
```

Comment: When you press debug which line is active in your code?

Comment: Form!frmwhatdates!cmdfilter.Visible = False

Comment: Try using :  Forms("frmwhatdates").cmdfilter.Visible = False

Comment: It's not `Form!..` but `Forms!...`.

Comment: Also, you don't need the bang `!` operator. This is perfectly valid: `Forms.frmwhatdates.cmdfilter.Visible`.